# Missing Bndtools Welcome dialog in Eclipse to setup a configuration project after creating new Bndtools project

Tags: eclipse, osgi, bndtools

I am following along with the [Bndtools tutorial](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html) with Bndtools 3.3 from the Eclipse marketplace, but I get stuck when, after creating the project, the tutorial says, "you will now see the 'Welcome' dialog. Click Next followed by Finish to allow Bndtools to setup a configuration project and import a basic repository." I don't see a Welcome dialog, or know how to open up the dialog to setup a configuration project. I am also stuck at the parallel step in the [Amdatu Tutorial](https://amdatu.org/application/tutorial/step1/) where it says, "After closing the dialog Bndtools will ask to create a Configuration project. Choose the 'Amdatu Configuration'."

I experienced additional problems in the Bndtools tutorial such as an error in Eclipse I had after creating the Bndtools project, "Missing Bnd Workspace.". I created a Bndtools workspace and the error went away but I wonder if the problems I'm having are part of a larger issue of the Bndtools tutorial being out of date or incomplete. I've tried the Bndtools tutorial with both Eclipse Neon and Eclipse Luna, which the Bndtools webpage says are supported, but get the same errors with either version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to switch to the bndtools perspective. On the botton left you find the view Repositories.

There you should see "No workspace configuration found". Directly beside there is a link to Create New Bnd Workspace...

This will create the conf project.

Comment: I don't see the link you're referring to, despite being in Bndtools perspective. Here is a screenshot in case I'm missing it: http://imgur.com/a/R1wG0 I am able to create a Bnd OSGi Workspace by going to File -> New in Eclipse. It does create a project named cnf so I guess that's a success although it doesn't inspire my confidence in the official Bndtools tutorial. Did you mean "cnf" when you wrote "conf"? I still don't know how to create an Amdatu-specific configuration, but that seems distinct enough to be a separate question.

Comment: You only see the link when you do not yet have a cnf project. The error shown in your screenshot hints that something with your cnf project was broken. I agree the tutorial should use a more reliable way.

Comment: The Link @ChristianSchneider was talking about is only shown after the first time you open the Eclipse with bndtools.
But you can always create the workspace via `Menu -> File -> Other ...` select folder `Bndtools -> Bnd OSGi Workspace` and complete the wizard with the template you want to use.